# Creating FTP Client Login Issue In java

Tags: java, apache, ftp

I am using commons.net api in order to create connection to the FTP server. simple code like

```
String Path = "D:\\FTP";
File ftpDirectory = new File(Path);
ftpDirectory.mkdirs();

FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();
ListenerFactory factory = new ListenerFactory();
factory.setPort(2221); 
factory.setServerAddress("192.168.1.110");

serverFactory.addListener("default", factory.createListener());
PropertiesUserManagerFactory userFactory = new PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
File userFile = new File("D:\\FTP\\users.properties");
userFactory.setFile(userFile);

//UserManager um = userFactory.createUserManager();
UserManager um =new PropertiesUserManager(new ClearTextPasswordEncryptor(),userFile,"admin");
BaseUser user = new BaseUser();
user.setName("test");
user.setPassword("test");
user.setHomeDirectory(Path);
um.save(user);

serverFactory.setUserManager(um);

FtpServer ftpServer = serverFactory.createServer();
ftpServer.start();
```

`FTPClient` Login as shown below

```
        FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.connect("192.168.1.110",2221);
        System.out.println("connect done");
        String loging_success = ftp.login("test", "test") == true ? "success" : "failed"; 
        System.out.println("login: "+ loging_success);
```

but i found trouble in order to login to the server.
i can start server easily but couldn't login to the server..
my output look like

> connect done

after long time get exception like

> org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection
>   closed without indication.    at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:313)   at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:290)   at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:474)  at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:547)  at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.user(FTP.java:693)     at
>   org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.login(FTPClient.java:872)    at
>   TestFTPServer.connectServer(TestFTPServer.java:213)   at
>   TestFTPServer.main(TestFTPServer.java:52)

I can't move forward from here...

Comment: So what error do you get?

Comment: That's a logging config error - follow the link given and apply one of the JARs suggested (not the -nop one though as you want to see the messages). Hopefully you will then get a useful error message.

Comment: ok fine, this solved by slf4j-nop dependency but no more logs and now exception like FTPConnectionClosedException.

Answer (score 3):

sorry for bothering you but finally i founded a solution..
it was my silly mistake..i was using commons.net-3.0 version when i upgraded that jar to latest version e.g. commons.net-3.3 the error was gone totally...so if you are getting this error just upgrade your jars just like that..

"have fun codding"..

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine (and runs fine), so it's probably something in your networking setup. Try changing the "192.168.1.110" address to "localhost" in client and server and see if that works. If it does then you need to investigate your network setup.

Comment: I have replaced IP to localhost but no effect founded

Answer (score -1):

its due to 'passive' mode set with ftp server which caused this issue.